# Can you use the possessive with the word "rest"?

Tags: possessives

For example,

> A group of 12 was trekking through the woods. Sarah's tent was all rolled up nicely. The **rest's** weren't.

Comment: It would be more natural to say, "the others' weren't".

Comment: I agree with @MicahWindsor but also think that the original is acceptable.

Comment: To add to the confusion, you could also say, "the rest weren't".